# Tfidf Vectorizer not working

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, tf-idf

I have a corpus(**Hotel Reviews**) and I want to do some NLP process including Tfidf. My problem is when I Applied Tfidf and print 100 features it doesn't appear as a single word but the entire sentence.
Here is my code:

**Note: clean_doc is a function return my corpus cleaning from stopwords, stemming, and etc**

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word',tokenizer=clean_doc, 
max_features=100, lowercase = False, ngram_range=(1,3), min_df = 1)
vz  = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(data['Review']))
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for feature in feature_names:
  print(feature)
```

it returns something like this:

```
love view  good room
food amazing recommended 
bad services location far
-----
```

any idea why? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you show us the code for your clean_doc function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely an error in your `clean_doc` function. The 'tokenizer' argument should be a function that takes a string as input and returns a list of tokens.

Comment: You're correct. The function returned the data as list of list. so I correct it. Thanks :)